# Automated Call About Tax Fraud

Tags: united-states, taxes, scams

Says something like "Fraud on tax return and you need to call this number as soon as possible."

I know there is a high probability that this is a total scam, but just-in-case:

1. How can I be absolutely sure?
2. This is happening more frequently every year and they're getting more clever - anyone know of any new dangers this year?

I swear, I am about to terminate having a cell phone forever.

Comment: https://www.irs.gov/uac/newsroom/scam-phone-calls-continue-irs-identifies-five-easy-ways-to-spot-suspicious-calls

Comment: If you think it might be genuine, then contact the appropriate agency using a phone number you find independently - for instance on their official web site.

Comment: There are always new dangers. Just assume that any unexpected call may be a scam, and call back to a number you have obtained from a trusted source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [IRS will NEVER EVER](https://www.irs.gov/uac/newsroom/scam-phone-calls-continue-irs-identifies-five-easy-ways-to-spot-suspicious-calls) initiate contact with you over the phone, email, text message, or social media. You will always get a letter in the mail. And even if you don't trust that, you can go to the IRS website to obtain their number and call them to confirm the letter/issue. There are many new scams occurring, the [FTC lists](https://www.consumer.ftc.gov/scam-alerts) all the ones that are making waves nationwide and it is updated on a regular basis.